# Convert week of the year to date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause

How can I get a date using the week of the year in Oracle SQL?

I need to search for entries created after the beginning of the current week. Currently, I get the week of the year by doing `select to_char(sysdate,'WW') from dual;`, but then I can't do

`select * from table where date > to_date(to_char(sysdate,'WW'), 'WW')` because I get

```
ORA-01820: format code cannot appear in date input format
01820. 00000 -  "format code cannot appear in date input format"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Format `WW` means: Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year. - is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to convert to a string and back, you can use truncate:

```
select * from table where date > trunc(sysdate,'WW')
```

Read more about [the `trunc()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) and [how the format model is applied](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html).

Notice that WW gives you the same day as the first day of the year, so right now that would give 2020-09-02, which is a Wednesday - possibly not what you'd expect. It depends on your requirements of course, but you might want to work with IW which always starts from Monday, and would give 2020-09-07. If you have a different start day you can add or subtract a day, e.g. if your week starts on Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

According to ORA-doc:

> **ORA-01820: format code cannot appear in date input format**
>
> **Cause:** A date specification contained an invalid format code. Only the following may > be specified when entering a date: *year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds*, Julian day, > A.M./P.M. and B.C./A.D.
>
> **Action:** Remove the invalid format code from the date specification.

You can't pass the weeknum to to_date() function. What you can do is e.g., the following

```
select * from table where date > (next_day(trunc(sysdate), 'SUNDAY') - 7)
```

Basically, next_day returns first date that meets specified weekday. Let's assume it's Monday 2020-09-07, next_day will return you the closest SUNDAY in the future, that is 2020-09-13, so you need to substract 7 to get date of the current week beginning. [You can read more about it here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm)